# Implementing dynamic ranking mechanism in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to implement this functionality as a part of a webapp I'm working on:

I have a file which contains entries in the form of

```
key1, val1, val2, val3, val3
key2, bval1, bval2, bval3
```

where key1 is a key to the values. Each val has a rank
that is the index in this array. e.g.val1 is rank 1, val2 is rank2
and so on.

Now, I want to a make a UI which will allow the user to
change the ranks of the values associated with a particular key
and finally write that changes out to the file.

Interacting with a database will be second part of the project
so would want to avoid that as of now. 
Can all of this be accomplished just by javascript(or jQuery)

If yes, how do I model each value and provide up and down
arrows to allow the user to change the ranking. Can anyone
point to some resources(or plugins) that I can read and learn?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Theory is nice, but we need to see code to give better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Although it binds your hands a bit visually, you might want to take a look at jQuery UI's Sortable and Dragable plugins. [A demo is here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable). If you follow their documentation and examples, modeling this becomes trivial.

As for writing it out to a file, you may not need to do that (assuming you're talking about doing this on the server). As long as the list of values is not huge, you can use [JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) to serialize your array/object and write it out persistently to a cookie.

Since you are writing out to a database, you may be specifically targeting Gears/Webkit/iOS browsers, in which case you may want to look into `window.localStorage` (it will eventually have full support in other browsers, but for now I think it can only safely be used in recent webkit browsers, including iPhone and iPad.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can store the data with cookies.

But the "write changes out to a file" part... might not be possible (i don't think it's possible) with JUST javascript/jquery, you would need server-side assist from PHP,Python,Ruby,Perl etc...